# how do I replace values in one column with strings in another one?

Tags: awk

I have a file like this:

```
head new_fileset_prefix_17.sampleT
ID_1 ID_2 missing
0 0 0
0 fam1000_G1000 0
0 fam1001_G1001 0
0 fam1003_G1003 0
0 fam1005_G1005 0
0 fam1009_G1009 0
...
```

I would like to get this output:

```
ID_1 ID_2 missing
0 0 0
fam1000 G1000 0
fam1001 G1001 0
fam1003 G1003 0
fam1005 G1005 0
fam1009 G1009 0
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'NR<3 { print; next; }; { split($2,a,"_"); print a[1] " " a[2] " " $3; }' file
```

Comment: `print a[1] " " a[2] " " $3;` = `print a[1], a[2], $3` - that's what `OFS` exists to do.

Answer (score 1):

The best tool for doing simple s/old/new on individual strings is sed:

```
$ sed 's/^[0-9]* \([^_]*\)_/\1 /' file
ID_1 ID_2 missing
0 0 0
fam1000 G1000 0
fam1001 G1001 0
fam1003 G1003 0
fam1005 G1005 0
fam1009 G1009 0
```

but in awk you could do:

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]/ && sub(/_/," ",$2){$0=$2 OFS $3} 1' file
ID_1 ID_2 missing
0 0 0
fam1000 G1000 0
fam1001 G1001 0
fam1003 G1003 0
fam1005 G1005 0
fam1009 G1009 0
```